# youtube 内でのイベント取得について

Tags: youtube-player-api

youtube 内での動画の「再生」や「一時停止」等のイベントを取得することは可能でしょうか？

埋め込み動画であれば、APIを利用して取得することは可能ですが、
youtube公式サイト内でのイベントを取得できるならしたいと思っています。

Comment: > youtube公式サイト内でのイベントを取得できる

というのがどのような利用方法なのかわからないのですが、iframeによるページヘのビデオ埋め込みとは違うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> YouTube公式サイト内でのイベントを取得できるならしたいと思っています。

YouTubeの利用規約の 2.A と 4.C にそれぞれ次のように記載されています。
https://www.youtube.com/static?hl=ja&template=terms

> 2.A 本サービス条件は、本サービス上への本コンテンツの投稿者でもある利用者を含む、本サービスの全ての利用者に対して適用されます。「本コンテンツ」には、本サービス上で閲覧し、本サービスを通じてアクセスし、または本サービスに投稿する、文章、ソフトウェア、スクリプト、グラフィックス、写真、音声、音楽、動画、オーディオビジュアルの組み合わせ、インタラクティブな機能及びその他のマテリアルを含みます。本サービスには、YouTubeのあらゆる側面が含まれます(YouTubeチャンネル、 YouTube｢Embeddable Player｣及びYouTube アップローダその他のアプリケーションなどの、YouTubeウェブサイトで提供される、すべての製品、ソフトウェア、及びサービスを含みますが、これらに限られません。)
>
> 4.C お客様は、本サービス自体の動画再生ページ、Embeddable Player、又はその他YouTubeが明示的に認めた手段以外のあらゆる技術及び手段を通じて、 本コンテンツにアクセスしないことに合意します。

Web版の動画プレーヤーに関連するAPIは YouTube iframe API のみなので、それ以外の方法でYouTubeのイベント（規約内の「本コンテンツ」に含まれる）にアクセスすることは、利用規約違反となります。